# Access Control: Database Fortify Issue

Tags: asp.net, fortify

So I'm running into a fortify issues that I'm having a hard time trying to find a solution

```
public Datatable GetData(string uid){
     Sqlcommand command = new SqlCommand();
     command.Parameters[0].value = uid  //Issue found here
```

The error occurs in the last line of code shown above indicating that the uid is the one that is causing the issue. I'm unsure as to how to approach this. Would sanitizing the string being passed into the function help remedy this issue? If so, how exactly is this different than Cross-Scripting?

Sorry if this is a silly question to ask but any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target", uid);
```

Comment: This solve a SQLInjection issue, but @Puff seems to have another issue (Access Control). This means that `uid` is directly pass to the SQL and generate the access control issue. @Puff, you must be sure that the `uid` did not expose another record in the database if the user have a chance to force the value to another.